# Show that the eigenvalues of a matrix are smaller or equal to the maximum norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a exercise in my linear algebra textbook that stumps me a bit.

You can show that all eigenvalues to a matrix have absolut value that are less than or equal to the maximum norm of a matrix. The maximum norm is the greatest of the sums you get through adding all absolut values of each element in a row.
Suppose that a matrix has real eigenvalues. Give a way to determine, with Exponentiation-method (translated from swedish), the greatest and smallest eigenvalue of the matrix.

In my textbook the exponentiation-method is a numerical method where you assume the nXn matrix have n different eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...\lambda_n$. Therefore those eigenvectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,...\vec{v}_n$ are a base in $R^n$.
If you iterate $A\vec{x}$ enough times you should have an approximation of the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue since:
$$\vec{x}=a\vec{v}_1+b\vec{v}_2+...+n\vec{v}_n$$
$$A^k\vec{x}=a\lambda_1^k\vec{v}_1+b\lambda_2^k\vec{v}_2+...+n\lambda_n^k\vec{v}_n$$
$$A^k\vec{x}=\lambda_1^k(a\vec{v}_1+b\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}^k\vec{v}_2+...+n\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_1}^k\vec{v}_n)$$
If $\lambda_1\gt\lambda_2\gt...\gt\lambda_n$ and $k\rightarrow \infty$
$$\frac{A^k\vec{x}\cdot \vec{x}}{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}}\rightarrow \lambda_1$$

The solution to the question is to calculate the eigenvalues for $A-\tau I$ and $A+\tau I$ which makes some sense to me if I accept that $\tau$ is the maximum norm. My question is how you can prove that all absolute eigenvalues are less than or equal to the maximum norm?

Comment: *"My question is how you can prove that all absolute eigenvalues are less than or equal to the maximum norm"* -- Gerschgorin Discs are one way

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $\| Ax \| \leq \| A \| \| x \|$ but also $\| Ax \|=\| \lambda x \|=|\lambda| \| x \|$, hence $|\lambda| \leq \| A \|$ whenever $A \mapsto \| A \|$ is a matrix norm induced by a vector norm.